# Renaming xml element of generic type only for specific type parameter

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

If I write this,

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (FileStream s = new FileStream("output.xml", FileMode.Create))
        {
            new XmlSerializer(typeof(Data<Item>)).Serialize(s, new Data<Item>());
        }
    }
}

[XmlType(TypeName = "Content")]
public class Item
{
}

public class Data<T>
{
}
```

output.xml will be

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DataOfItem xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
```

but I want "DataOfItem" to be "DataOfContent". Is there any way to do this with changing only Data class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly what you wanted, but you can provide a custom root name when you create the XmlSerializer. Like this:

```
var xmlTypeAttr = typeof(Item).GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<XmlTypeAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
var customRoot = new XmlRootAttribute("DataOf" + xmlTypeAttr.TypeName);
new XmlSerializer(typeof(Data<Item>), customRoot).Serialize(s, new Data<Item>());
```

Comment: I didn't know I can specify the root name! Thanks! And, I realized my question may be able not to be answered correctly because other answers of related questions are to create a wrapper class.